# Can I select an instance without resorting to TypeApplications?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have the following type classes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}

class Interpretation i where
  type Context i :: * -> *

class Interpretation i => Interpret i a where
  type Interpreted i a :: *

  int :: a -> Context i (Interpreted i a)
```

Which basically encode interpretation functions from `a` to `Interpreted i a` wrapped in some context.

I've written these instances:

```
data X = X

instance Interpretation X where
  type Context X = Identity

instance Interpret X Int where
  type Interpreted X Int = Bool

  int :: Int -> Identity Bool
  int x = pure (x == 0)
```

Now suppose that I need to use `int` above to interpret an `Int` into a `Bool`, for instance in the following function:

```
f :: Int -> Bool
f = -- use int somehow
```

If I define `f` as follows:

```
f x = int x
```

The compiler will complain:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Interpreted i0 Int’ with ‘Bool’
  Expected type: Int -> Identity Bool
    Actual type: Int -> Context i0 (Interpreted i0 Int)
  The type variable ‘i0’ is ambiguous
• In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘int’
  In the expression: runIdentity . int
  In an equation for ‘f’: f = runIdentity . int
```

By using `TypeApplications` I can select the right (and only available) instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications       #-}

-- ...

f :: Int -> Bool
f = runIdentity . int @X
```

But I was wondering whether such instance could be selected without resorting to `TypeApplications`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, `int` has an ambiguous type. That's because `i` only appears in the signature within `Context i` and `Interpreted i a`, which are type families and as such not (necessarily) injective, as witnessed by [Isaac van Bakel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413656/745903). Ambiguous types can only be resolved with type applications (and IMO this is a perfectly good approach).

You can however prevent the ambiguity. The traditional way is to use associated *data* families instead of type families; these have the type information baked in and are therefore always injective:

```
class Interpretation i where
  data Context i a

class Interpretation i => Interpret i a where
  type Interpreted i a :: *
  int :: a -> Context i (Interpreted i a)

instance Interpretation X where
  newtype Context X a = XContext (Identity a)

instance Interpret X Int where
  type Interpreted X Int = Bool
  int :: Int -> Context X Bool
  int x = XContext $ pure (x == 0)

f :: Int -> Bool
f n = case int n of
  XContext a -> runIdentity a
```

An alternative is the more recent [injective type families extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typefamilydependencies#injective-type-families).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

class Interpretation i where
  type Context i = (r :: * -> *) | r -> i

class Interpretation i => Interpret i a where
  type Interpreted i a :: *
  int :: a -> Context i (Interpreted i a)

instance Interpretation X where
  type Context X = Identity

instance Interpret X Int where
  type Interpreted X Int = Bool
  int :: Int -> Identity Bool
  int x = pure (x == 0)

f :: Int -> Bool
f = runIdentity . int
```

Note that in this case, you won't be able to use `Identity` for another `Interpretation` instance.

Comment: I didn't know about these alternatives (and the injectivity problem). Thanks.

Regarding the use `TypeFamiliesDependencies` does the constraint `r -> i` means that one couldn't define a second instance like the one shown in [Isaac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413656/2289983)'s answer?

Comment: Yes, the injectivity annotation basically prevents you from writing two instances that both have `type Context _ = Identity`, and therefore avoids the ambiguity between two such instances.

Answer (score 4):

No. Imagine, if we had in another module

```
instance Interpretation Y where
  type Context Y = Identity

instance Interpret Y Int where
  type Interpreted Y Int = Bool

  int :: Int -> Identity Bool
  int x = pure (x /= 0)
```

And define `f` as you have done - what should the behaviour be?

I assume you also don't want to use something like `Proxy`, which would allow you to pass in a type variable without needing to use `TypeApplications`, but would still require specifying the instance you'd want to use.

Comment: So it doesn't matter in this case that there's only one instance defined (and accessible) in that module?

Comment: @DamianNadales, we have an open world assumption for classes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about it. Makes sense.